# Process Watcher For Mac

Tags: macos, mac, process, monitoring, notifications

I'm looking for something that I'm sure is out there, but I can't find it.

I have a long running program (Matlab simulation) that runs for 24 hours or more on the Mac in my office.  Occasionally the program crashes, so I'm looking for a program or command that can periodically check to make sure the process is still running, and if it is not, send me an email so I can log in remotely and restart the program/fix the problem.

The more user-friendly the better, as I'd like non-advanced users to be able to use it on their own.

Comment: I don't know if there's such a program, but how about this: Use `launchd` (with `StartInterval`) to periodically launch a script, use `ps` to find the process you're looking for, `mailx` or `Mail.app` scripting to send mail.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used Matlab in a while, but from what I understand from [MathWorks support](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-2RHEPI/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-2RHEPI), if your code crashes you would get a `matlab_crash_dump.XXXX` file in your home folder, where `XXXX` is a number. You can then use [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php) to detect the addition of that file and then use an Automator workflow to send you an email.

I would have liked to test this but don't currently have anything that crashes Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this with a simple script. Any script you're comfortable with, be it bash, ruby, applescript or whatever.

I had a bash script set on a cron job that would check if a Teamspeak server was  running and if not, start it.

Comment: Understand a script could do this, I was just hoping there was a utility out there, that was a little more user friendly, and would let me be lazy and not have do much more than pointing and clicking :)

Comment: Ugh. Pointing and clicking is so much work. Wouldn't you rather just type a few keystrokes?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep a process running (or, rather, restart it if it exits) use `launchd`. There's a recipe for keeping TextEdit alive [here](http://www.macgeekery.com/tips/all_about_launchd_items_and_how_to_make_one_yourself), and [Lingon](http://lingon.sourceforge.net/) is available as a GUI to set it up.

This isn't perfect for your particular problem, though - `launchd` will restart your process *whenever* it exits, regardless of whether it was successful or not. This could be a big pain if your program were to overwrite the perfectly good output from the previous run. To get round this, you could wrap your program in a script (a shell script would do) that would run the program, then, if it was successful, remove the `launchd` job before exiting. Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

/my/matlab/program
#$? is the exit value of your program - convention is 0 for success, non-zero otherwise
if [ $? = 0 ]
    launchd unload keep.my.matlab.running
fi
```

[edit]

If Matlab produces output as fideli suggests, you could use a [folder action](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=mac/10.4/en/mh1976.html) on the folder that Matlab would put its error report into. Simply write an Applescript or Automator workflow that takes the files that have been added, checks if they are a Matlab error and, if so, sends you an e-mail. One of the built-in ones is called "new item alert" and is probably a good starting point for some genetic modification.